# A question from CGAN which indicates me "InvalidArgumentError"

Tags: python, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I was trainning the MNIST dataset from keras. And I copy the example from keras. First I met the problem, I tried to record each variable when concating. But I didn't find any strange shape that the ERROR indicates me. Here is the code:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_size = 64
num_channels = 1
num_classes = 10
image_size = 28
latent_dim = 128



(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
all_digits = np.concatenate([x_train, x_test])
all_labels = np.concatenate([y_train, y_test])


all_digits = all_digits.astype("float32") / 255.0
# print(all_digits.shape)
all_digits = np.reshape(all_digits, (-1, 28, 28, 1))
# print(all_digits.shape)
all_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(all_labels, 10)


dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((all_digits, all_labels))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(batch_size)

generator_in_channels = latent_dim + num_classes
discriminator_in_channels = num_channels + num_classes

discriminator = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.layers.InputLayer((28,28,discriminator_in_channels)),
        layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),strides=(2,2),padding='same'),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),strides=(2,2),padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.GlobalMaxPool2D(),
        layers.Dense(1)
    ],
    name='discriminator'
)
generator = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.layers.InputLayer((generator_in_channels,)),
        layers.Dense(7*7*generator_in_channels),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Reshape((7,7,generator_in_channels)),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(8,(4,4),strides=(2,2),padding='same'),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(8,(4,4),strides=(2,2),padding='same'),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2D(1,(3,3),padding='same',activation='sigmoid')
    ],
    name='generator'
)
generator.summary()
discriminator.summary()

class ConditionalGan(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,discriminator,generator,latent_dim):
        super(ConditionalGan,self).__init__()
        self.discriminator = discriminator
        self.generator = generator
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.gen_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name='generator_loss')
        self.disc_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name='discriminator_loss')

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [self.gen_loss_tracker,self.disc_loss_tracker]

    def compile(self,d_optimizer,g_optimizer,loss_fn):
        super(ConditionalGan,self).compile()
        self.d_optimizer = d_optimizer
        self.g_optimizer = g_optimizer
        self.loss_fn = loss_fn

    def train_step(self,data):

        real_image , one_hot_labels = data

        image_one_hot_labels = one_hot_labels[:,:,None,None]
        image_one_hot_labels = tf.repeat(image_one_hot_labels,repeats=[image_size*image_size])
        image_one_hot_labels = tf.reshape(image_one_hot_labels,shape=(-1,image_size,image_size,num_classes))

        #Disciminator

        random_latent_vector = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size,latent_dim))
        
        print(random_latent_vector.shape)
        print(one_hot_labels.shape)
        
        random_vector_labels = tf.concat((random_latent_vector,one_hot_labels),axis=1)

        generator_image = self.generator(random_vector_labels)

        fake_image_and_labels = tf.concat([generator_image,image_one_hot_labels],-1)
        real_image_and_labels = tf.concat([real_image,image_one_hot_labels],-1)
        
        print(generator_image.shape)
        print(real_image.shape)
    
        combine_images = tf.concat([real_image_and_labels,fake_image_and_labels],0)

        labels = tf.concat([tf.ones((batch_size,1)),tf.zeros((batch_size,1))],0)
        
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            pred = self.discriminator(combine_images)
            d_loss = self.loss_fn(labels,pred)
        grads = tape.gradient(d_loss,self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
        self.d_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads,self.discriminator.trainable_weights))

        #Generator

        random_latent_vector = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size,latent_dim))
        random_vector_labels = tf.concat((random_latent_vector,one_hot_labels),-1)
        
        print(random_latent_vector.shape)
        print(one_hot_labels.shape)
        
        misleading_labels = tf.zeros((batch_size,1))
        
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            fake_image = self.generator(random_vector_labels)
            
            print(fake_image.shape)
            print(image_one_hot_labels.shape)
            
            fake_image_and_labels = tf.concat([fake_image,image_one_hot_labels],-1)
            pred = self.discriminator(fake_image_and_labels)
            g_loss = self.loss_fn(misleading_labels,pred)
        grads = tape.gradient(g_loss,self.generator.trainable_weights)
        self.g_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads,self.generator.trainable_weights))

        #Monitor loss.
        self.gen_loss_tracker.update_state(g_loss)
        self.disc_loss_tracker.update_state(d_loss)
        return {
            'g_loss':self.gen_loss_tracker.result(),
            'd_loss':self.disc_loss_tracker.result()
        }


cond_gan = ConditionalGan(
    discriminator=discriminator, generator=generator, latent_dim=latent_dim
)
cond_gan.compile(
    d_optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0003),
    g_optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0003),
    loss_fn=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
)

cond_gan.fit(dataset, epochs=20)
```

And the ERROR is below. And i have search for some answering. Some of them are solving this kind of problems by editing the batch_size. I have tried, but failed. The error doesn't indicate the right line. This code is compiling in Kaggle Notebook. So maybe the location doesn't right.

```
    InvalidArgumentError:  ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [64,128] vs. shape[1] = [48,10]
     [[node concat (defined at tmp/ipykernel_34/2191800439.py:95) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_38770]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node concat:
 IteratorGetNext (defined at tmp/ipykernel_34/2191800439.py:156)    
 random_normal (defined at tmp/ipykernel_34/2191800439.py:90)

Function call stack:
train_function
```

THANK U FOR ANSWERING!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here `random_vector_labels =  tf.concat((random_latent_vector,one_hot_labels),-1)`

It throws "InvalidArgumentError" error because **random_latent_vector shape [64,128]** and your **one_hot_labels shape[48,10]** **don't match**. your random_latent_vector has 64 rows of data but your one_hot_labels only has 48 rows of data. So when you are trying to concatenate two arrays with different dimensions make sure that they have the **same number of rows**. So make sure your random_latent_vector shape matches with one_hot_labels shape.